# Airflow and LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator and payload

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm using Airflow 2.7.3.
I have a start-process task that pushes to Airflow Xcoms two values: schema (string), and ids (list of integers).

Then I try to create a LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator like this:

```
my_lambda = LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator(
    task_id='my-lambda',
    payload={'schema': '{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="start-process", key="schema")}}',
             'ids': '{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="start-process", key="ids")}}'},
    dag=dag
)
```

This will not work, since Airflow expects the payload to be byte-array.

But how do I convert the payload to byte-array inside the LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator?

If I try something like this:

```
    payload=bytearray(json.dumps({'schema': '{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="start-process", key="schema")}}','ids': '{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="start-process", key="ids")}}'}), 'utf-8'),
```

the jinja template does not get evaluated.

I tried to read the Airflow documentation and examples but the Airflow examples using LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator use hard-coded simple values and not XComs.

Answer (score 0):

`payload` argument in [LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/lambda_function/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.lambda_function.LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator) accept either byte or string object. So it would be enough to dump your dict to JSON-string

```
payload=json.dumps(
  {
    "schema": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='start-process', key='schema') }}",
    "ids": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='start-process', key='ids') }}",
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue. I misread the error message.